# NSBundle pathForResource doesn't work for subdirectory localization?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, nsbundle

I saw quite a few questions regarding `[NSBundle MainBundle] pathForResource` (using inDirectory or not), but my case seems different.

My problem is: Yes, it works fine for whatever files in subdirectory if without localization. For example, it returns the correct path for the file `data/a/words.txt` when I use

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"words.txt" ofType:nil inDirectory:@"data/a"]
```

However, after I localized the `words.txt`, let's say the real path becomes: `data/a/en.lproj/words.txt`, then the above code cannot find the path anymore.

I checked the file in the .app package and the file has been copied into the correct path `(data/a/en.lproj)`, it's just somehow the code cannot find it.

I'm using XCode 5.1.1

Isn't `pathForResource` supposed to find the text automatically?

Comment: When you build/run from Xcode sometimes old files remain in their old places, so try deleting the app from the device/simulator, doing a clean, and then rebuilding.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `forLocalization` to `pathForResource`, like this:

```
NSArray* availableLocalizations = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations];
NSArray* userPrefered = [NSBundle preferredLocalizationsFromArray:availableLocalizations forPreferences:[NSLocale preferredLanguages]];

NSString *indexPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"txt" inDirectory:@"data/a" forLocalization:[userPrefered objectAtIndex:0]];
```